# how to set kendo grid dataSource in the form ajax success?

Tags: ajax, forms, kendo-ui, grid

Through the dialog I upload excel file , and parse the file on the server then return the json data to ajax success, but when I want to set the kendo grid datasource in the ajax success, it submit the form again, and this is my code, who can help me? Thank you very much!
the ajax code:

```
var form = $('#idForm');
form.submit(function (e) {
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            var grid = $('#demo2').data('kendoGrid');

            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: response.data
            });

            grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(123);
        }
    });
    //e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    return false;
});
```

Comment: How loads data your grid? If scenario is that grid loads data from database, then you save something into database and now you want refresh your grid. Refresh grid should be enough.

Comment: Have you tried, instead of everything you have on your success function, `$('#demo2').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read()`?

Comment: Try to go ahead and define a dataSource on the grid initially, with data: [] , then when you get the JSON back, simple call $("#demo2").data("kendoGrid").dataSource,data(response.data);

Comment: thank you very much @Robin Giltner,i call $("#demo2").data("kendoGrid").dataSource,data(response.data); and it have resolve my problem. But there has the new problem that after data binding. I can't update, delete, or even add row in kendo grid ,,,what should i do? I don't konw how to do?

Comment: thank you very much @Ademar

Comment: thank you very much @chiapa